# Directing emails of one account to multiple folders by Outlook Rules

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I hope there is someone who have an idea about this issue.

***I want to archive a sender's emails(for example send form : test@tect.com) to             more than one folder in outlook concurrently by using automatic rule function.***

Is this possible?

Comment: Please remember [to accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer- Thank you.

Comment: Hello Omar, I figure it out that it can be used as a script rule. So it is working. Thank you very much. –

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with help of script rule and **`vba`** code.

the following code creates a copy of the identified message as it arrives and then moves the copy message to multiple to folders.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MoveItems(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim CopyItem As Object

    Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olInbox = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set olItems = olInbox.Items

    '// loop
    While TypeName(olItem) <> "Nothing"
        Set olDestFolder = olInbox.Folders("TEMP1") 'Folder
        Set CopyItem = olItem.copy
        olItem.Move olDestFolder

        Set olDestFolder = olInbox.Folders("TEMP2") 'Folder
        olItem.Move olDestFolder

        Set olDestFolder = olInbox.Folders("TEMP3") 'Folder
        olItem.Move olDestFolder

        '// Add more folders here

        Set olItem = olItems.FindNext
    Wend

    Set olNameSpace = Nothing
    Set olInbox = Nothing
    Set olDestFolder = Nothing
    Set olItems = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set CopyItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Need to use the Copy method of the MailItem class instead.